# Java: how to simplify complicated annotations

Tags: java, annotations

We have quite a complicated structure of annotations which can be placed on a field. This structure is placed on a lot of fields with only 1 parameter changing. The rest is just copy-paste code. This approach works, but is kinda ugly:

```
@Type(type = "com.company.ConstantClass", parameters = @Parameter(name = "parameterClass", value = "com.company.ChangingClass"))
ChangingClass parameter;
```

In the above example, only the parameter `value` ever changes, and the rest is just copy-paste.

What I would like to do, is to create a "shortcut" annotation with only the `value` parameter. And while we're at it, the parameter could be changed from `String` to `Class`, to make the code less susceptible to refactoring errors.

For example:

```
@Shortcut(value = ChangingClass.class)
ChangingClass parameter;
```

One problem is that the `@Type` annotation can only be placed on a field or a method, so I cannot simply create an "annotated annotation".

Comment: Maybe put a common part on a Class level?

Comment: @annotations are used thereafter to provide simplicity over complex configuration explicitly, very useful.

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking is not feasible.
What you can do is specify default values.

```
public @interface Type
{
   String type() default "com.company.ConstantClass";
   Parameter parameter();
}

public @interface Parameter
{
   String name() default "parameterClass";
   String value();
}
```

I think the result is pretty clean.

```
@Type(parameter = @Parameter("com.company.ChangingClass"))
private ChangingClass parameter;
```

**OR**, you have to refactor the code that extract the annotation values to use default values. This way you can have an annotation with a single property only.

Comment: This is not an option because those are 3rd-party annotations.

Comment: Let me arrive at home. We'll find a solution.

Comment: @Jardo if they are part of a 3rd party library, you might want to implement a custom class loader to change the bytecode of the "bit" that scan for these annotations.

Answer (score 0):

If the 3rd party library use the annotation, it must need load the class object. So I guess there is a API like

```
public void load(Class<?> clz);
```

You can define your `@Shortcut` and handle it before load the class. You can use my utility class [`AnnotationUtil`](https://github.com/XDean/Java-EX/blob/363362cb5ca48d72bd1c2a67ad410a7f314ad3c8/src/main/java/xdean/jex/util/reflect/AnnotationUtil.java) to add/remove/change annotation at runtime:

```
  public static void processShortcut(Field f) {
    Shortcut s = f.getAnnotation(Shortcut.class);
    if (s != null) {
      AnnotationUtil.removeAnnotation(f, Shortcut.class); // remove @Shortcut
      Parameter p = AnnotationUtil.createAnnotationFromMap(Parameter.class, ImmutableMap.of("name", "parameterClass", "value", s.value().getName())); // create @Parameter
      Type t = AnnotationUtil.createAnnotationFromMap(Type.class,
          ImmutableMap.of("type", "com.company.ConstantClass", "parameters", new Parameter[] { p })); // create @Type
      AnnotationUtil.addAnnotation(f, t); // add it on field
    }
  }
```

Let's test our code

```
public static class User {
  @Shortcut(User.class)
  public Object parameter;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  Class<?> clz = User.class;
  // process shortcut on all fields
  Arrays.stream(clz.getFields()).map(ReflectUtil::getRootField).forEach(f -> processShortcut(f));
  // submit to 3rd-party lib
  thirdParty(clz);
}

public static void thirdParty(Class<?> clz) {
  // this mock your 3rd party entry
  Arrays.stream(clz.getFields()).forEach(f -> System.out.println(f + "\t" + f.getAnnotation(Type.class)));
}
```

And output

```
public java.lang.Object xdean.stackoverflow.java.annotation.Q48386072$User.parameter    @xdean.stackoverflow.java.annotation.Q48386072$Type(type=com.company.ConstantClass, parameters=[@xdean.stackoverflow.java.annotation.Q48386072$Parameter(name=parameterClass, value=xdean.stackoverflow.java.annotation.Q48386072$User)])
```

You can see the `@Type` really add to the field.

You can find complete code on my [github](https://github.com/XDean/StackOverflow).